# On RHEL if there's a new kernel, doing a stop and start instead of reboot loads the new kernel?

Tags: kernel, rhel, reboot

If we do a `yum update -y --security` and there is a new kernel, can we do a stop and start of the instance instead of reboot to load the new kernel?

Comment: What exactly are you stopping and starting?

Comment: If there is any kernel upgrade most probably it required a reboot. Just in case if you want to check whether server required reboot or not you can run this command `needs-restarting -r`

Comment: @omajid stopping and starting an ec2 instance

Answer (score 0):

No.

The old kernel is what is running your OS until you reboot.

The reboot may load a new kernel.

That doesn't include technologies that patch an existing kernel to pick up new changes, like `ksplice`, `kpatch` or `kGraft`. AFAIK, none of these technologies are used out of the box by `yum update`.